# How can I understand the channel for rabbitMQ, is it the same design idea with session in hibernate for database

Tags: hibernate, design-patterns, rabbitmq

How can I consider the channel for rabbitMQ, is it the same design idea with session in hibernate for database?

Answer (score 0):

You could think of them as being similar.

In RabbitMQ the Channel is used to access the Connection in a similar way to the Session being used to access the Connection nHibernate.

This [article](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/297146/Creating-an-AMQP-Sample-App-using-RabbitMQ) provides a good overview of how to use Channel's in RabbitMQ.